# Can I graft a citrus using two different techniques simultaneously?

Tags: citrus, grafting, bud

I am thinking of grafting a mandarin on a citrus tree that is most probably a grapefruit, but not sure. As I understand, they're compatible as both a citrus trees.

My question is - can I graft a bud and with a cleft onto the same tree at the same time? I'm pretty new to this and I want to increase my chances. I probably won't have another source of scion later, and I wonder how much stress is this going to put the grapefruit in if I graft two times essentially?

Answer (score 1):

When producing multi-variety apples, the usual practices is to do a single bud for each cultivar.

By using the same style at the same level in the tree, they are getting equal resources.

But easy answer:  Try it.  Leave enough of the tree below your graft attempt to try again next year if it doesn't take.